# Complicated postfix relay

Tags: postfix

I have a server running postfix with ~20 users that receives mail and sometimes resend the mail to external domains. Is it possible to configure postfix to drop all outgoing mail (to all users) into a folder/file, and then when I initiate it, send all mail in said folder? I want to go through all mail by hand before it is sent from the server.

Comment: What for big brother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (mostly).

You'll want to setup an smtpd [`access(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) policy `(check_recipient_access type:table)` that sends items into the [`hold queue`](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#hold_queue), probably in [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions).

The message queue can be seen with `postqueue -p`.
Messages in the hold queue are denoted by a trailing `!` on their QUEUEID, e.g.:

```
19ABE1094521!   49261 Mon Nov 14 20:59:59  MAILER-DAEMON
```

The contents of held messages can be sent to stdout using `postcat -q $QUEUEID`.

Held messages may be released using `postsuper -H $QUEUEID`, requeued using `postsuper -r $QUEUEID`, or deleted using `postsuper -d $QUEUEID`.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for but didn't think about. I was totaly into "put stuff here - read - refeed to postfix"